# How to extend subclass?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, subclass

I need to extend all models in Joomla with my own class with a few methods, so i creating one more class

```
class Staff extends JModelLegacy{

    public function lol(){
        die('lol');
    }
}
```

And extend model with it

```
require JPATH_BASE.'/components/com_component/misc/extend_model.php'; 

class ComponentModelSites extends Staff{
public function saveSiteInfo($input){
        $this->lol();
}
```

The problem is that when i call `saveSiteInfo` i get fatal error that method `lol` not found, but `var_dump(get_class_methods($this));` show all methods of `JModelLegacy`. Where i wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you're creating a ComponentModelSites and calling saveSitesInfo()?

Comment: @Ray it crates with http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JController/getModel

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, you must be doing something [else] wrong.

See http://ideone.com/tDouwQ

```
<?php
class Staff {

    public function lol(){
        die('lol');
    }
}

class ComponentModelSites extends Staff{
public function saveSiteInfo($input){
        $this->lol();
}
}
$cms = new ComponentModelSites();
$cms->saveSiteInfo(null);
```

Comment: the staff must be extended with JModelLegacy

Comment: @Kirix: That shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

```
<?php

class Staff{

    public function lol(){
        die('lol');
    }
}


class ComponentModelSites extends Staff {

        public function saveSiteInfo($input){
                $this->lol();
        }
}

$obj = new ComponentModelSites();
$obj->saveSiteInfo(1);
```

Gives expected results. You have to include wrong file or do something silly but I can't tell from the give example.

Comment: the staff must be extended with JModelLegacy

Comment: That doesn't matter at all. Extending from JModelLegacy will not do any harm. Look for the problem elsewhere